# Static inference of function type argument in standard C++98 from function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I have a shared library exporting unary functions like:

```
extern "C" void foo(int);
extern "C" void zoo(double);
```

The library is consumed by a compiler without C++11 support. I want to infer the function types statically in a struct from the function name.

I can write:

```
template <typename T, void(*)(T)> struct A{ typedef T arg_t; };
```

For this I have to explicitly specify the type `T` when instantiating the template, i.e. I have to write

```
A<int, &foo>
```

instead of just

```
A<&foo>
```

Given this info is embedded in the pointer type, is there a way to extract is statically?

Comment: Support for something like `A<&foo>` wasn't added until C++17. Without C++11, I don't think it's possible in standard C++.

Comment: This may be an XY problem. If you write a helper `template<typename T> T get_return_type(void(*)(T))`, you can write `decltype(get_return_type(&foo))`.

Comment: @MSalters: if just `decltype` was available without C++11, it would have been a solution.

Comment: You can do that inside a function template, but not otherwise, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to define only a new type in structure *A*.
Let's assume it has a variable *v* of type *T* inside.
In this case I would use the C++ function overloading feature like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    void foo(int x) { printf("foo(%i)\n", x); }
    void zoo(double x) { printf("zoo(%f)\n", x); }
}


template <typename T> struct A { typedef T arg_t; arg_t v; };


void foo_zoo(int x) { foo(x); }
void foo_zoo(double x) { zoo(x); }
void foo_zoo(A<int> x) { foo(x.v); }
void foo_zoo(A<double> x) { zoo(x.v); }


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int xi = 1;
    double xd = 2.0;

    A<int> ai; ai.v = 10;
    A<double> ad; ad.v = 20.0;

    foo_zoo(xi);
    foo_zoo(xd);

    foo_zoo(ai);
    foo_zoo(ad);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler/linker will use proper version of *foo_zoo* function this case without any run-time overhead. Unused versions for *foo_zoo* may be discared by linked if needed.